# VB.NET Select Case - what is the correct statement?

Tags: vb.net, select-case

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
Private Function resolveSiteName(ByVal plantName As String, ByVal siteName As String) As Integer
    Dim siteId As Integer = Nothing
    Dim fullName As String = plantName & siteName
    Select Case fullName
        Case fullName.Contains("Example" And "Example2" And "Example3")
            siteId = 0
    End Select
    Return siteId
End Function
```

I'm guessing my `Select Case fullName` is wrong, because when debugging it, the conditions are met and it just skips over assigning the `siteId`.

I also tried just this

```
Case fullName.Equals("Exactly what full name is")
```

just to test to see if that would work...and it still skipped over the assigning part.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have more than just that case, i just trimmed out the extra stuff that wasn't necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this would not even compile if you'd use an `If`-clause(which is more appropriate here):

```
If fullName.Contains("Example" And "Example2" And "Example3") Then
    ' this doesn't compile since you cannot concat a string with And
    ' you want to check if fullName equals to one of the strings anyway
    siteId = 0
End If
```

If you want to check multiple items at once, define a collection, add all to it and then use `Contains`:

```
Dim siteNames = { "Example", "Example2", "Example3" }
If siteNames.Contains(fullName) Then
    siteId = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work too:

```
Select Case fullName
   Case "Example", "Example2", "Example3"
      siteId = 0
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Case fullName
   Case "Example"
      siteId = 0
   Case "Example2"
      siteId = 0
   Case "Example3"
      siteId = 0
End Select
```

Comment: It's not going to work, there is no fall-through in VB Select Case.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
Select Case True
    Case fullName.Contains("Example")
        siteId = 0
End Select
```

Or for your second try:

```
Select Case fullName
    Case "Exactly what full name is"
        siteId = 0
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Select Case fullName
```

with

```
Select Case True
```